# external libraries on lambda - is efs mount and layer working in different?

Tags: lambda, librosa, amazon-efs, aws-lambda-layers, soundfile

I'm currently trying to use python librosa package on AWS lambda and following this blog.
https://gianlucazuccarelli.medium.com/librosa-and-aws-lambda-20e48f23b57e

According to this blog, even after installing the librosa package on mounted EFS, the author still adds some extra lambda layers (soundfile, ffmpeg).

isn't it possible to just add them also to efs?
Does libraries installed with lambda and efs work different?

+) has anyone succeed adding soundfile on lambda and how? went through all of the process and has a soundfile dependency issue..